# Issue with matrix construction in Fortran

Tags: matrix, fortran

I have a simple subroutine for constructing a tight binding Hamiltonian. It constructs a matrix with 2x2 blocks only in the diagonal and nearest off diagonals. It is like this (there are many parameters defined above in my code):

```
subroutine hlayer(s,r)
complex*16,dimension(1:lda,1:lda) :: s,r
integer :: i,j
s(:,:)=zero   
r(:,:)=zero
! hamiltonian of the layer
do i=1,lda,2
  s(i,i)     = es
  s(i,i+2)   = tss
  s(i,i+3)   = tsp
  s(i+2,i)   = tss
  s(i+3,i)   = tsp

  s(i+1,i+1) = ep
  s(i+1,i+1+1)   = tsp
  s(i+1,i+2+1)   = tpp
  s(i+1+1,i+1) = tsp
  s(i+1+2,i+1) = tpp
end do
! interaction between layers:
do i=1,lda,2
  r(i,i)     = tss
  r(i,i+1)   = tsp
  r(i+1,i)   = tsp
  r(i+1,i+1) = tpp
end do
end subroutine
```

When I call the subroutine in the main program (it runs with no problem by the way):

```
call hlayer(a,b)
```

I get the following matrix for a, the s variable in the subroutine (lda=10 in this case):

```
 1.000 0.000  0.100 -0.150  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.100
 0.000 1.200 -0.150  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
 0.100 0.000  1.000  0.000  0.100 -0.150  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
 0.000 0.000  0.000  1.200 -0.150  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000
 0.000 0.000  0.100  0.000  1.000  0.000  0.100 -0.150  0.000  0.000
 0.000 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.200 -0.150  0.000  0.000  0.000
 0.000 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.100  0.000  1.000  0.000  0.100 -0.150
 0.000 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.200 -0.150  0.000
 0.000 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.100  0.000  1.000  0.000
 0.000 0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  0.000  1.200
```

and I do not understand where the top right 0.1 comes from, since in my subroutine all the entries of the matrix (except those assigned explicitly) are set to zero. 
Is there any problem with the indexes that I am not taking into account ??

Comment: How does `lda` get the value you want in the subroutine?

Comment: Hi. It is a integer parameter set to 10 in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You are exceeding the array bounds. Compile with error checking (`-fcheck=all` or `-check` or something else, depending on the compiler) to diagnose similar errors.

For example

```
 s(i+1,i+2+1)
```

both `i+1` and `i+2+1` is too large when `i` is close to `lda` and is more then the error bound. There are similar issues in all rows.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. On the other hand, do you how to check errors with intel compiler (ifort)?

Comment: `-check`, it is in the answer

Comment: Partially... It is - check bounds. -check all is worth starting with as you get bounds, interfaces and unitialized.

Comment: It is not worth to check just bounds. He is likely to have many errors.